# How do I make Wordpress "Page" link in the top nav bar go to an external URL?

Tags: links, urls, configuration, headers

I would like the [Wordpress page link as shown here](https://skitch.com/chirag/fciqf/wordpress-page-link) go to an external URL instead of going to page. What is the best way to set this up? I'm running Wordpress 
3.1.3. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto

> Appearance -> Menus -> Create a new menu -> Add your link as custom
>   link

Comment: Thanks Viru. Just so it's clear multiple menu items are added as new custom links within the same menu